# SQL foreign key references

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Does

```
FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES A(a),FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES A(b)
```

Has the same meanning as in :

```
FOREIGN KEY (a,b) REFERENCES A(a,b)?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Having two `references` statement means that both `a` and `b` appear in `A` *independently*.  That is, they are valid values, but they don't have to appear together.  Think of "February 30".  It has a valid month and a valid day of month, when each are checked separately.

Having a single `references` statement means that `a` and `b` appear in `A` *together*.  Hence, "February 30" would fail this test.

Traditionally, a foreign keys refer to a primary or unique key.  This is not enforced in MySQL, but it is a useful guideline (and also useful in practice).  So, in the example with two `references`, this would usually mean that both `a` and `b` are unique.  Although this is not enforced, it gives a good indication of how the keys will be used.  In the second case, the combination of `a` and `b` is unique.

Comment: So if you have tables A(a primary) B(b primary,c primary) and C(a primary,b1 primary,b2 primary,c primary) how would you go on and define it in proper Sqlite?

Comment: @OfekRon . . . I think you should ask another question with the details of these tables and what you want to do.

Comment: there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702764/sql-primary-and-foreign-key thanks!