# SQL Primary and Foreign key

Tags: android, sqlite

if you have tables

`A(a primary key)`

`B(primary key (b ,c))`

and `C(primary key (a,b1,b2,c)  references A(a),B(b),B(b),B(c))`

how would you go on and define it in proper Sqlite for Android?

Comment: In [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702528/sql-foreign-key-references#comment-34593089), you were told to specify "the details of these tables and what you want to do".

Answer (score 0):

I think you would do:

```
C(a) references A(a)
C(b1, c) references B(b, c)
C(b2, c) references B(b, c)
```

But it is a little hard to tell without examples of the data and knowing what the columns and tables mean.